# How do I redirect to the current page in Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, redirect, servlet-filters

I have a page say:  **/myapp/test.jsp?queryString=Y**.
The filter needs to redirect to current page.
It should go to **/myapp/test.jsp**  (without the query string).
The below seems to bring it to to the context root:  **/myapp**.
I am running in WAS6.1.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
{
   boolean blnNeedToRedirect = true;
   if (blnNeedToRedirect) {
      httpResp.sendRedirect(".");
      return;
   }

   chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [HttpServletrequest.getRequestURI](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29). This should work for you:

```
httpResp.sendRedirect(httpReq.getRequestURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

httpReq.getRequestURI() Gives you the servlet path and it should work as follows.
In order to redirect to the same page, run the next command:

```
((HttpServletResponse) httpResp).sendRedirect(httpResp.encodeRedirectURL(httpReq.getRequestURI()));
```

Another Option is to add the Header `Location` with a status code 302 as follows:

```
((HttpServletResponse) httpResp).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY); 
((HttpServletResponse) httpResp).addHeader("Location", request.getRequestURL().toString());
```

Comment: Isn't the "requested page" also "the same page"? Please clarify with an example.